# C++ Expression Template: operator what?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename E>
class VecExpression{

public:

  operator E&(){
    return static_cast<E&>(*this);
  }
  operator E const&() const{
    return static_cast<const E&>(*this);
  }
};
```

could someone please explain to me this code?  I've never seen this kind of operator overloading.  What is its return type? Does it have any parameters?  Can I see a usage or maybe where it's getting called in the source?

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the conversion operator.

```
int i = (int)a;
```

that would invoke a::operator int()

Comment: the *explicit* cast is not needed.

Comment: Yea, and C-style casts are _bad_ and naughty in C++. Do `static_cast<int>(a)` please if you need a cast; rely on implicit conversion otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

`VecExpression` is a template so the operators are returning a const or non-const reference to the template type `E` of the class. It's an implicit conversion operator. It takes no parameters, just takes a use of `VecExpression<E>` and allows its use in a context where it needs an `E`.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of it as the cast operator.

It is defining the cast VecExpression to an object of type E (or a reference to object of type E). Basically this allows you to pass an object of type VecExpression to any function that  takes an object of type E and the compiler will auto convert using this operator.

```
int stuff(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

int code()
{
    VecExpression<int>  x;
    return stuff(x); // cast x to E (which is an int).
}
```

Comment: Conversion operator, not cast. You don't perform a cast, but an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: That's why I used the phrase `You can think of it as`. As in most situations it looks like using a cast operation. Though yes you are technically correct it is a conversion.

Comment: Sure, you can think of it as the cast operator, but you'd be wrong. Let's not propagate incorrect terminology to those who don't know any better, eh?

Comment: @LokiAstari: Could you tell me how to assign an initial value for `x` inside `code()`, or how do you intend to use `VecExpression`? Thank you.

Comment: @QiangLi: I have no idea. This is a class that the OP has, it is not part of the standard library.